# How to print string from first character to determined character with java?

Tags: java, string, character

I have string

```
Intel Corporate|Lot 8, Jalan Hi-tech 2/3|Kulim Hi-tech Park|Kulim Kedah 09000|Malaysia
Samsung Electronics||#94-1, Imsoo-dong|Gumi Gyeongbuk 730-350|Korea, Republic Of
```

How do I print vendor name like Intel Corporate, Samsung Electronics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) ...

I think you'll find something like...

```
String value = "Intel Corporate|Lot 8, Jalan Hi-tech 2/3|Kulim Hi-tech Park|Kulim Kedah 09000|Malaysia";
System.out.println(value.split("\\|")[0]);
value = "Samsung Electronics||#94-1, Imsoo-dong|Gumi Gyeongbuk 730-350|Korea, Republic Of";
System.out.println(value.split("\\|")[0]);
```

Should suffice...

Comment: @user2009370 `String#split` splits the screen across the specified delimiter.  It will return an array of `String`s that are separated by this delimiter.  If you have a look at the example I provided, it use the array index of `0` (`value.split("\\|")[0]`) to get the first element.

Comment: @user2009370 As you are only interested in the first element (company name), I simply grabbed the first element out of the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use split, like this:

```
String[] tokens = phrase.split("\\|");
```

Then print them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

Comment: Check your regular expression, I think you might find it doesn't work ;)

Comment: You need to escape that like `\\|`